# tkinter combobox for file list from folder

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to use a combination of a combobox, 2 buttons and a textbox widget for displaying the text from *.txt files. but my code has a problem. I cannot proceed further, help is needed. please see the code below.

```
f3 = Frame(page2, bg="purple", width="800", height="2")
f3.pack(side=TOP)

f4 = Frame(page2, bg="purple", width="800", height="60")
f4.pack(side=BOTTOM)

arr = []

combo = ttk.Combobox(f3, height="10", width="69")
combo.pack(side=LEFT)


def load():
    tid = tb2.get("1.0", END).replace('\n', '').replace("Destination 
       Folder :", '')
    arr = [x for x in os.listdir(tid) if x.endswith(".txt")]
    for i in arr:
         combo.insert('end', i)


def display():
tb3.delete(1.0, END)
if len(tb2.get("1.0", END)) > 2:
    tid = tb2.get("1.0", END).replace('\n', '').replace("Destination 
Folder :", '')
    file = combo.get()
    selected = os.path.join(tid,  file)
    with open(selected) as textfile:
        tb3.insert('end', textfile.read())
else:
    messagebox.showinfo(title="PROCEDURAL ERROR", message="FOLDER is 
          not set. \nSet Destination")



pbtn7 = Button(f3, text="LOAD", activebackground="magenta", 
    activeforeground="white", bd="5", bg="powder blue",
           command=load, fg="purple", font=('arial', 10, 'bold'))
pbtn7.pack(side=LEFT)


pbtn6 = Button(f3, text="DISPLAY", activebackground="magenta", 
   activeforeground="white", bd="5", bg="powder blue",
           command=display, fg="purple", font=('arial', 10, 'bold'))
pbtn6.pack(side=RIGHT)

tb3 = Text(f4, height="40", width="100")
tb3.pack()
#========================================

root.mainloop()
```

The whole idea is get a path in form of string which is modified and stored in variable 'tid', and then this path is used for browsing all text files in the folder to be listed in combobox. and then the display button to be used for showing the text of the selected file

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBAIg.png)

Comment: We can't run that code, and saying "my code has a problem" doesn't give us much information. Please explain the problem, and make your code a [mcve] that illustrates that problem.

Comment: I have uploaded the picture to show you the output. It is clear that the combobox isn't populated the way it should be

Comment: Or to put it simple, just tell how to add *.txt files in a folder to combobox list and display them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop to load a combobox. You can assign a list as values:

```
combo['values'] = arr
```

then you can display it by:

```
def display():
    with open(combo.get()) as textfile:
        tb3.insert('end', textfile.read())
```

You really should read the documentation. It's not that hard :)

Comment: thanks, this part is solved. Now how to get the current selected in combobox and display the text file in textbox tb4, can you help me in getting the function for diplay and use it in button pbtn6

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: the error i get is `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'notes20180612110407.txt'` it of course is due to the lack of full path, which is stored in tid

Comment: I need to supply path to textfile which is stored in tid.

Comment: Google "os.path".

Comment: Finally I have been able to get the display function as correct in above code.